# What cooking techniques depend on controlled temperature between 100 and 120 degrees celsius?

Tags: temperature

Many preparation techniques rely on controlled temperature. Sous Vide, Chocolate making, etc.

I am trying to identify specific techniques that have their range in 100 to 120 degrees. For example, [Fudge needs 115 degrees](http://www.ricardocuisine.com/articles/food-chemistry/400-for-successful-fudge-every-time-).

Context: new [Thermomix (version 5)](http://www.superkitchenmachine.com/2014/21204/new-thermomix-tm5.html) advertises the maximum temperature increase from 100 to 120 degrees. I am trying to figure out what difference that can make.

Comment: Good grief, that thing looks like something out of *Star Wars*!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.  Techniques like sous vide aim for a specific target temperature because the goal is to never exceed that temperature and excessively denature proteins.  In baking or candymaking, specific temperature is important, but more because it's the best stand-in for things like water content or browning.  Their raising the maximum temperature to 120C just means that they put in a more powerful heating element.

Comment: I am asking for what specific techniques rely on this specific 20 degrees range. Something that was not possible before, when limited at 100 degrees but is possible now at up to 120.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of places where the ability to get to 120˚C might be useful.

You've already touched on one, which is cooking sugar.  With a range up to 120˚C you get up to the firm ball stage, allowing you to make syrups, fudge, caramel, fondant, butter creams, marshmallows, meringues, and toffees.

You can get some caramelization (mostly of fructose) at that temperature.

I don't know how practical it would be with the machine in question, but you can get Maillard reactions at [temperatures that low](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/what-temperature-does-the-maillard-reaction-occur) if you use prolonged cooking time and/or optimize the environment by adding alkaline.

---

This machine does not seem to have a pressurization feature, but that would be another place where the higher temperature would be useful.  At a pressure of 1 bar/~15 psi above the existing atmospheric pressure, water in a pressure cooker can reach a temperature of up to 121 °C (250 °F), depending on altitude. Pressure cooking can be used to quickly simulate the effects of long braising or simmering.